# deseralize php Json in vb.net

Tags: php, json, vb.net

I trying to get a array in VB.NET, but I have troubles for `deserialize`, I don't know if my format is bad or what, but first the data is a std object

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6797892
            [marca] => xxx
            [details] => yyy
            [price] => rrr
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [Por] => 1           
                                            [$$hashKey] => 03F
                                        )    
                                )    
                            [Tipo] => mouse
                            [price] => 1.65
                            [$$hashKey] => 03D
                        )
                      [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [Por] => o
                                            [$$hashKey] => 03J
                                        )    
                                )    
                            [Tipo] => teclado
                            [price] => 1.65
                            [$$hashKey] => 03H
                        )    
                )    
            [$$hashKey] => 03B
        )    
)
```

next i use json_encode(in php):result is:

```
[{"Id":"6797904","marca":"xxx","Pais":"yyy","Liga":"rrr","Jornada":"3","info":[{"Items":[{"Por":"1","Cuota":"2.25","$$hashKey":"03I"}],"Tipo":"mouse","price":2.25,"$$hashKey":"03G"}],"$$hashKey":"03E"}]
```

and using

```
....
    file_put_contents($file, print_r($current, true) );
...
```

I save it in `items.txt`, and I load it in vb.net, but I don't know what is the correct way to convert into an array using:

```
Dim str As JArray = JArray.Parse(TextBox1.Text)   

    Dim results As Object = str("Id").ToString
```

Comment: Sorry bout my last comment. remove the `print_r`  it does not just format your json but it also adds characters making it invalid. use `print_r` only to get a HUMAN readable version.

Comment: Define, describe and clarify "I have error".

Comment: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Array position index expected.

Comment: This is 100% caused by the `print_r` as pointed out by @mvbrakel - remove it and try again.

Comment: i have the same error

Comment: Change code to this `file_put_contents($file, $current );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put in it an answer format.

The use of `print_r` is not correct here.

```
...
file_put_contents($file, print_r($current, true) );
...
```

The definition for `print_r` as per php.net:

> print_r  —  Prints human-readable information about a variable.

This means extra characters are added to make it readable to humans, but not for machines. It even creates invalid JSON, causing VB.NET to generate an error.

Update your code to

```
...
file_put_contents($file,$current);
...
```

And it should work

Comment: please check the str value in debbug time:

Comment: {[" & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    "id": "6797904"," & vbCrLf & "    "marca": "xxx"," & vbCrLf & "    "details": "yyyy"," .....

Comment: Could you add a example piece of the generated text file? With print_r removed

Comment: well, the problem is have a parent index so i can call with str(0)("id"), thanks for all